# Tmux current pane border not obvious

Tags: bash, tmux

I'm struggling to tell which pane is the current one in tmux if there are only two. The border only seems to highlight the adjoining edge which makes it impossible to tell. Here's a Gif to highlight what I mean.[image]

I'm in bash, and the config for that looks thus

```
set-option -g pane-border-fg white
set-option -g pane-active-border-fg green
```

Anyone got any tips to make it more obvious?

Comment: This issue is resolved in the current version of tmux. When there are only two splits the upper/lower half of the split line is colored to indicate left/right split.

Comment: You might consider posting this as the answer?

Comment: Isn't it possible to get tmux to have 1px borders around each of all panes?

Comment: The problem is that if each pane has an identical border, you can't determine which is active. As @Phani says, it's less of an issue in more recent versions, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This issue is resolved in the current version of tmux. When there are only two splits the upper/lower half of the split line is colored to indicate that the left/right split is active

[image]

Comment: Also gets confusing when it comes to horizontal layout. Left half highlight = top pane, but.. not so very obvious unless you look out for the active cursor.

Answer (score 18):

I think I've finally found a way that makes it really clear for me. Using the following in the `.tmux.conf`.

```
set -g window-style 'fg=black,bg=colour253'
set -g window-active-style 'fg=colour234,bg=colour231'
```

I get the focused / active window in lighter color and the non-focused / inactive ones a bit grayed out.

I've tweaked my color palette a lot, but using your favorite colors (note the british spelling in the tmux.conf) should allow for adjustments.

Example of active (lower right corner) vs inactive:

[image: example of active vs in-active]

Comment: Although the split does change colour half way now, I still find it confusing at times. There's no mistaking this solution!

Answer (score 10):

Good question; I wish I had a better answer. The `display-panes` command (C-b q by default) shows the active pane with a red number. Given only two panes, you still have to remember that red is active, blue is inactive.

If you set `display-panes-color` to something with low constrast with your background color, it will be less visible than the (by default) red active pane number.

Comment: I've pretty much always used `display-panes` precisely because of this problem.

The other issue of course is having to set a low `repeat-time` so you don't move to Vim then try and move your cursor only to move back to another pane.

Will probably continue with `display-panes` I've got enough contrast on the current pane number to be pretty useful. Thanks a lot for the input, I'll just have to bear it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using @chepner's answer, you can improve your experience by binding `Alt + q` to display panes for custom milliseconds in your `tmux.conf` using:

```
bind -n M-q display-panes -d 300
```

*where 300 is the amount of milliseconds in my case*

It is better than just sending the `display-panes` command with the default combination (C-b q by default) because is quicker to launch and last for a custom time